Is it wrong to say $d/dx (\ln(x)) = \frac{1}{|x|}$?
Is it wrong to say $d/dx (\ln(x)) = \frac{1}{|x|}$?
Let's just say it's been a while since I've taken calculus and I got some details confused on my midterm. Is this necessarily incorrect considering $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{|x|}$ for all values on the relevant domain $x>0$?

If you are really only considering positive $x$, then it's correct. Note however (important!) that: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x},\ln(|x|)=\frac{1}{x},\quad,x\neq0$$And the RHS does not have an absolute value

It is not wrong. But it is also pointless. ln x is defined over the reals only for positive x. If you intend to extend that definition, your identity doesn't help.
